# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook library for C++

Tags: c++, outlook

I want to send an email through outlook.
I want to use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook library. But the problem is that dll is contains C# methods.
Is there anything that is equivalent to that library? or should I use a different library that is more compatible with C++.

Any suggestions on an appropriate library? any resources pointing to a relevant code will also be appreciated!

Comment: Asking for a library is off-topic, but here also an XY problem. MSDN is quite clear that `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` is a .Net wrapper of the COM Outlook interface, and MSVC++ supports COM directly.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Object Model is not C# specific. The interop dll created when you add a reference to Outlook in your C# project is nothing but a glorified binary header. It does not contain any actual code.

Using OOM in C++ is not any different from using any other IDispatch-friendly COM library - use #import to import the type library, declare and use objects, etc.